# How to extract relationship from text in NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk

Hi I'm trying to extract relationships from a string of text based on the second last example here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120907184244/http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/relextract.html

From a string such as "Michael James editor of Publishers Weekly" my desired result is to have an output such as:

> [PER: 'Michael James'] ', editor of' [ORG: 'Publishers Weekly']

What is the best way to do do this? What format does extract_rels expect and how do I format my input to meet that requirement?

---

Tried to do it myself but it didn't work.
Here is the code I've adapted from the book. I'm not getting any results printed. What am I doing wrong?

```
class doc():
 pass

doc.headline = ['this is expected by nltk.sem.extract_rels but not used in this script']

def findrelations(text):
roles = """
(.*(                   
analyst|
editor|
librarian).*)|
researcher|
spokes(wo)?man|
writer|
,\sof\sthe?\s*  # "X, of (the) Y"
"""
ROLES = re.compile(roles, re.VERBOSE)
tokenizedsentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
for sentence in tokenizedsentences:
    taggedwords  = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
    doc.text = nltk.batch_ne_chunk(taggedwords)
    print doc.text
    for rel in relextract.extract_rels('PER', 'ORG', doc, corpus='ieer', pattern=ROLES):
        print relextract.show_raw_rtuple(rel) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
```

> text ="Michael James editor of Publishers Weekly"
>
> findrelations(text)

Comment: Have you verified if the intermediate steps are working correctly? You should try and do that first, and identify what step of your code (tokenizing, pos tagging, ner, relation extraction) is not doing what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: the output i get when i change the the chunking to use ne_chunk (instead of batch_ne_chunk) is (S
  (PERSON Michael/NNP)
  (PERSON James/NNP)
  ,/,
  editor/NN
  of/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Publishers/NNP Weekly/NNP))

Comment: so is the problem that batch_ne_chunk is not working?

Comment: both dont return any results. but when using the ne_chunk the print doc.text line produces the output in my previous comment, and when using the batch_ne_chunk  the print doc.text produces the error:   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/chunk/named_entity.py", line 49, i                                                                                                 n _feature_detector
    pos = simplify_pos(tokens[index][1])IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: ok.. even i have faced issues like this the last time i tried using nltk.. being an actively developed library nltk's api has probably gone through some changes which has lead to this code to not work anymore.  also setting up nltk sometimes requires you to download a bunch of model files using the nltk.download method in an interactive shell (ipython).. my advice to you would be to play with all these nltk functions in an ipython terminal and see what their input/output specs are.

Comment: As you can see, the nltk source code is living in '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/' on your machine, so you could open any of these files (e.g. 'chunk/named_entity.py') and compare what you were giving these functions to what these functions seemed to be expecting. Once you understand what these functions need and what they return, developing such code will be a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 4):

here a code based on yours (just few adjusts) that work well ;)

```
import nltk
import re 
from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk_sents
from nltk.sem import relextract


def findrelations(text):
    roles = """
    (.*(                   
    analyst|
    editor|
    librarian).*)|
    researcher|
    spokes(wo)?man|
    writer|
    ,\sof\sthe?\s*  # "X, of (the) Y"
    """
    ROLES = re.compile(roles, re.VERBOSE)

    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
    chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences)


    for doc in chunked_sentences:
        print doc
        for rel in relextract.extract_rels('PER', 'ORG', doc, corpus='ace', pattern=ROLES):
            #it is a tree, so you need to work on it to output what you want
            print relextract.show_raw_rtuple(rel) 

findrelations('Michael James editor of Publishers Weekly')
```

(S
  (PERSON Michael/NNP)
  (PERSON James/NNP)
  editor/NN
  of/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Publishers/NNS Weekly/NNP))